# Java generics code compilation issues when building outside of Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I have configured a Maven build for a very small GWT project I'm having. Compiling/running from Eclipse causes no problem, but when I execute Maven build, I've got compilation issues in one single place (this is GWT 'client-side' code, but I'm not sure if that's the case). Maven/compile output:

```
[..]SmartTable.java:[63,52] ')' expected
[..]SmartTable.java:[63,53] ')' expected
[..]SmartTable.java:[63,69] ';' expected
[..]SmartTable.java:[63,71] not a statement
[..]SmartTable.java:[63,77] ';' expected
[..]SmartTable.java:[63,79] not a statement
```

.. where this specific line defined as following:

```
final Comparator<T> comparator = ((SmartTable<T>.ComparableColumn) column).comparator;
```

As you have guessed, I'm iterating over all columns defined for this generics-class (which I call 'SmartTable'), and getting a comparator (of course, if column instanceof SmartTable.ComparableColumn) for further operations. 
Classes 'Column' and 'ComparableColumn' are nested in SmartTable, and their headers looks as following:

```
public abstract class Column {
    // private String id;
    private String caption;
    private int width;
    private Filter<T> filter;
...
public class ComparableColumn extends Column {
    private Comparator<T> comparator;
...
```

When it gets compiled from Eclipse, I have no problems in packaging WAR (without 'clean' - simply package which will work since Eclipse configured to place .class files in the same target directory used by Maven) and deploying/running it correctly.

I've already tried changing maven-compiler-plugin  and  configuration (setting values 1.5, 1.6; and 1.4 - for sake of experiment to see if it will start complain on generics in general), but that wasn't of help. Eclipse project compiler compliance is default (1.6). It seems that I have no other compilation issues with the other generics code.

Tried to make it as short as possible, but not sure if I managed to do it well :)

**EDIT: More of code by demand**

```
public class SmartTable<T> extends FlexTable {
    private List<Column> columns = new ArrayList<Column>();
    ...
    private Comparator<T> currentComparator;
...

    public void init(Comparator<T> defaultComparator) {
        this.currentComparator = defaultComparator;
        ...
        int index = 0;
        for (Column column : columns) {
            ...
            if (column instanceof SmartTable.ComparableColumn) {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                final Comparator<T> comparator = ((SmartTable<T>.ComparableColumn) column).comparator;
            ...
    }
...

    public abstract class Column {
        // private String id;
        private String caption;
        private int width;
        private Filter<T> filter;
        private List<WidgetCreator<T>> widgetCreators;

        public Column(/* String id, */String caption, int width, Filter<T> filter, List<WidgetCreator<T>> widgetCreators) {

...

    public class SimpleColumn extends Column {
        public SimpleColumn(/* String id, */String caption, int width, Filter<T> filter, List<WidgetCreator<T>> widgetCreators) {
            super(/* id, */caption, width, filter, widgetCreators);
        }

...

    public class ComparableColumn extends Column {
        private Comparator<T> comparator;

        public ComparableColumn(/* String id, */String caption, int width, Filter<T> filter,
                List<WidgetCreator<T>> widgetCreators, Comparator<T> comparator) {
            super(/* id, */caption, width, filter, widgetCreators);
            this.comparator = comparator;
        }

...

}
```

**EDIT2: Actual problem seems to be very concentrated :)**

```
public class SmartTable2<T> {
    public void init() {
        Column c = new ComparableColumn();

        final Comparator<T> comparator = ((SmartTable2<T>.ComparableColumn) c).comparator;
    }

    class Column {

    }

    class ComparableColumn extends Column {
        Comparator<T> comparator;
    }
}
```

**EDIT3: Some thoughts, hopefully closer to the solution**
.. so this doesn't compile simply with javac, throwing exactly same compilation errors. So what I've learned just now: Eclipse uses it's own internal Java compiler - which is part of JDT Core (hope I have not misunderstood it); so might it be the case that JDT Compiler is able to compile such a syntax, while Sun's JDK javac is not??? (oops, Oracle not Sun)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Casting to an inner class with generics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156705/casting-to-an-inner-class-with-generics)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this syntax:

```
Comparator<T> comparator = (Comparator<T>) ((SmartTable.ComparableColumn) column).comparator;
```

EDIT:
The cast is useless:

```
Comparator<T> comparator = ((SmartTable.ComparableColumn) column).comparator;
```

Does this resemble your scenario ?

```
public class Main {

    public static <T> void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SmartTable<T>.Column column = new SmartTable<T>().new Column();
        Comparator<T> comparator = ((SmartTable.ComparableColumn) column).comparator;

    }

    static class SmartTable<T> {
        class Column {

        }
        class ComparableColumn extends Column {
            Comparator<T> comparator;
        }
    }

}
```

This compiles fine with javac (with unchecked warnings, of course), while trying to compile the cast to (SmartTable.ComparableColumn) results in exactly the errors in your post.

EDIT (of all edits):
Your question seems to have been asked before: [Casting to an inner class with generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156705/casting-to-an-inner-class-with-generics) and the answer seems to be a compiler bug: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6665356

Comment: This will result in other compilation errors (I suppose these are sort of GWT post-compilation errors): [INFO]    Validating newly compiled units
[INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/D:/[..]/SmartTable.java'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 63: Cannot cast from SmartTable<T>.Column to SmartTable.ComparableColumn

Comment: Hmm... remove the <T> in the SmartTable<T>.Column declaration above... However, on my machine with the same class declaration it compiles just fine. This cast problem should only be an unchecked warning...

Comment: Code (as you suggested after edit): final Comparator<T> comparator = ((SmartTable.ComparableColumn) column).comparator; Output: [INFO]          [ERROR] Line 63: Cannot cast from SmartTable<T>.Column to SmartTable.ComparableColumn

Comment: I understand that SmartTable is the only generic class: SmartTable<T>... Can I see all the three class declarations ? (I suppose both Column classes are non-static inner classes of SmartTable). And the declaration of the column variable above that line ?

Comment: The pre- and post- edit code versions are identical -- that cast is just useless, since the unchecked warning is raised anyway.

Comment: I've placed fragments of my SmartTable (preserving the whole structure) which definitely should help to see the big picture. (See edit of the original question)

Comment: I'll have a look: I've posted a snipped that I tested; for start, does my last code fragment compile on your machine ?

Comment: If that "Cannot cast" error occurs, it must first refer to the instanceof test -- that also checks for incompatibility, the same as the explicit cast, and instanceof comes before in your code. However, with your exact code I manage to compile it with javac 1.6 with no problem.

Comment: Hey Costi, I think you've pointed me to the right direction. Your code does compile well, but it doesn't reflect situation 100%. So I created mini-SmartTable (see my EDIT2), and it really doesn't compile with javac, giving well known errors! So the question is really narrowed down to: why the class compiles in Eclipse, but doesn't compile with javac? Could you please check if SmartTable2 compiles well on your machine? Thank you in advance.

Comment: No, the cast to (SmartTable<T>.SortableColumn) doesn't compile on my machine, and I found the answer why here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156705/casting-to-an-inner-class-with-generics  -- which actually seems to lead here: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6665356

Comment: However, I'm still confused about one thing: why can't you use my "fix" (actually, workaround) ? Doesn't your initial code for SmartTable compile fine with that fix ?

Comment: Yes, indeed! This is it! Thank you! Please, add it to your answer so that others may also see it immediately without digging through our comments :)

Comment: Your fix will work if it's compiled with javac, but when I'm compiling the whole stuff, it fails with ERRORs I've posted above -these seem to be gwt-maven-plugin errors.

Comment: hmm... that's really strange... especially since it should first fail on the instanceof test (if the compiler really thinks the cast is impossible). :-/

Comment: I will dig into this in more detail later (investigate GWT compiler behaviour); and if I will stuck at some point - will create a new question (or post some comment here if success). Meanwhile I'm accepting your original answer and closing this question due to real breakthrough :) Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Please let me/us know if you find the GWT compiler issue, as this may also be useful for others.

Answer (score 1):

Use it the following way. I mean add the following plug in directly to the pom.xml file.

org.apache.maven.plugins
    maven-compiler-plugin
      
       1.5
       1.5